# Esoteric JS Question

Tags: javascript, theory

Is there any particular reason that this sort of construct would not work in JS? (JSLint does not accept it.)

```
(function(function(){

    }){

})()
```

I can see this type of chaining going on forever, or at least as far as one would want/need.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: `function(){...}` is not a valid argument name, so is not valid in another function's argument list.  Are you perhaps thinking of something like `(function(foo){...})(function(){...})`?

Comment: Your second _function_ is the parameter values, and is where the parameter _name_ should be.  It's like the "5" in the following:   function abc(5) { .... }

Comment: I'm passing the return value of one function as the argument to the next. This is not valid JS.

Answer (score 3):

Did you mean:

```
(function () {
// ...
})((function () {
// ...
})());
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... yeah, it wouldn't work because it's not meaningful to embed an anonymous function in the argument list of an anonymous function.  What are you trying to specify, there?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an anonymous function which accepts a function as an argument, and immediately pass it another anonymous function:

```
(function(fn) { })(function() { })
```

But I can't think of a single useful reason for doing that.